# How do I find the distribution function of this random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have the following problem:

> Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be indipendent identical distributed random variables. Let $F_X$ be the distribution function of these random variables. Find the distribution function of $$Y=max\{X_1,...,X_n\}$$ in terms of $F_X$.

My idea was the following. So I know that $F_X:\Bbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ such that $F_X(x)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x,...,X_n\leq x)$. Now since all $X_i$'s are independent we know that $$F_X(x)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x,...,X_n\leq x)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x)\cdot \cdot \cdot \Bbb{P}(X_n\leq x)$$W.L.O.G. assume that $Y=X_i$ for some $1\leq i\leq n$. Then $$F_Y(x)=F_{X_i}(x)=\Bbb{P}(X_i\leq x)=\frac{\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x)\cdot \cdot \cdot\Bbb{P}(X_{i-1}\leq x)\cdot \Bbb{P}(X_{i}\leq x) \cdot \Bbb{P}(X_{i+1}\leq x)\cdot \cdot \cdot  \Bbb{P}(X_n\leq x)}{\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x)\cdot \cdot \cdot\Bbb{P}(X_{i-1}\leq x)\cdot  \Bbb{P}(X_{i+1}\leq x)\cdot \cdot \cdot  \Bbb{P}(X_n\leq x)}=\frac{F_X(x)}{\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x)\cdot \cdot \cdot\Bbb{P}(X_{i-1}\leq x)\cdot  \Bbb{P}(X_{i+1}\leq x)\cdot \cdot \cdot  \Bbb{P}(X_n\leq x)}$$

I'm not sure if this works so or if it doesn't. Could maybe someone help me and correct me if I'm wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: have you tried searching online? this is a standard result in most texts - look up distributions of order statistics, here's one of the top hits: https://www.colorado.edu/amath/sites/default/files/attached-files/order_stats.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have overcomplicated things.

$$\begin{align}F_Y(x) &=\mathbb P(Y \le x) \\ &=\mathbb P(\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\} \le x) \\ &= \mathbb P(X_1\le x, \ldots,X_n\le x) \\ &=\mathbb P(X_1\le x)\cdots \mathbb P(X_n\le x) &\qquad\text{(independence)}\\ &= F_X(x)^n &\qquad\text{(identically distributed)}\end{align}$$

Comment: Sorry why does the last equality holds because in my opinion $F_X(x)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x,...,X_n\leq x)$. I agree that I can split this and write it as $\Bbb{P}(X_i\leq x)^n$ for some $1\leq i\leq n$ but then I somehow don't see why we can write this as $F_X(x)^n$

Comment: You asked about the third equality: If the maximum of the $X_i$ is less than or equal to $x$ then each of the $X_i$ must be less than or equal to $x$, since one of them is equal to the maximum and the others are  less than or equal to that one.  Similarly if  each of the $X_i$ is less than or equal to $x$ then the maximum of the $X_i$ must be less than or equal to $x$; the maximum is one of the $X_i$.  So they are the same event.

Comment: Sorry I understood the third equality in the mean time. Therefore I deleted my remark and wrote one about the last equality

Comment: You asked about the last equality.  $\Bbb{P}(X_i\leq x) = F_X(x)$ for each $i$ since it is its distribution function (and they all have the same distribution)

Comment: Hmm sorry I don't get this one.

Comment: In the question, you say near the beginning: "Let $F_X$ be the distribution function of these random variables."  What do you think this means?

Comment: I think this means that $F_X(x)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x,...X_n\leq x)$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134911/discussion-between-aprozz-and-henry).

Comment: I don't chat.  That is in fact $F_Y(x)$.  The joint distribution function is $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n) =\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,\ldots,X_n\leq x_n)$ but that is a function of an $n$ dimensional variable  and I think it is reasonable to read $F_X(x)$ as being intended to be the marginal distribution function  of each $X_i$.

Comment: But if $F_X(x_1,...,x_n)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,...,X_n\leq x_n)$ then I would get $\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1)\cdot \cdot \cdot \Bbb{P}(X_n\leq x_n)$? Sorry I don't see it right now because we have never introduced the notion of marginal distribution.

Comment: $\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1,\ldots,X_n\leq x_n)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1)\cdots \Bbb{P}(X_n\leq x_n)$ if you have independence. $F_{X_1}(x_1)=\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1)$ is the marginal distribution of $X_1$

Comment: Sure and then I can write this as $\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x_1)^n$ right? But then how do I get to $F_X(x)$?

Comment: Because my reading is $F_X(x) =\Bbb{P}(X_1\leq x)$ as it is described as its distribution function

Comment: ah but this is only a definition?